# Service-to-service communication: API Gateway vs. Service Mesh

Tags: cloud, microservices, api-gateway

AFAIK:

- **API Gateway**: user-to-service communication
- **Service Mesh**: service-to-service communication

But I cannot find a good explanation (and bibliography) explaining why using API Gateway (such as Apigee) is not suitable for inter-process communication.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difference is mainly a structural one as noted here:

"The service mesh pattern primarily focuses on handling traditionally what has been referred to as "east-west" remote procedure call (RPC)-based traffic: request/response type communication that originates internally within a datacenter and travels service-to-service. This is in contrast to an API gateway or edge proxy, which is designed to handle "north-south" traffic: Communication that originates externally and ingresses to an endpoint or service within the datacenter."

[More information on this website](https://www.infoq.com/articles/service-mesh-ultimate-guide/#the-service-mesh-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

**API Gateway:** It is the first entry-point for request coming towards downstream APIs/services. It is responsible for API management. It handles only L7 (HTTP) routing capability.

**Service Mesh:** Uses a side-car pattern to sideline non-business logic concerns (TLS, Circuit breaker pattern .etc.) away from your running application. It has L4/L7 routing capability.

Check the decision tree for better understanding:
[image: API cs SM]

Comment: Your source: https://www.cncf.io/blog/2020/03/06/the-difference-between-api-gateways-and-service-mesh/

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway is not right tool for inter-service communication because the need is different. As someone rightly answered  API Gateway is for North-South and service mesh is for East-West communication. API Gateway mediates every API call whereas this is not required in inter-service communication. If you try to implement APIGW for internal services, it will cost you more and also degrade the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Apigee Adapter for Istio. it provides features like traffic management, security and monitoring.

Link - https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/istio-adapter/concepts